# How to sculpt folded skin

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to copy this model:[image]

what tools should I use to create the wrinkles and growths on the neck? Is there a seed up the process or must it all be done by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Texture panel in Sculpt Mode, as shown below:

[image: Texture panel]

This will apply a texture to your brush. If it doesn't look right, you can adjust the size of the texture under the "Size" portion of the panel. Additionally, you can use "Spacing" under the Stroke panel to adjust the sample rate(?) of the stroke.

Edit: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pV8qEjZKJlc) is a video of the texture brush in action, at around 35 minutes in.

Comment: will the texture be able to create the larger growths on near the bottom of the neck and at the back?

Comment: For the back, I'm pretty sure he just used another texture. As for the bottom, I think you'd have to mess around with it a bit to get it right.